# <gz/common/Plugin.hh> not recognised as a header file

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, plugin

I am trying to build command line tools for converting Quaternions to Euler angles, Euler angles to Quaternions, etc. as per [this issue](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-math/issues/198) and this is the code for the plugin I created:

```
#include <gz/math/Quaternion.hh>
#include <iostream>
#include <gz/common/Plugin.hh>

namespace gz {

class QuaternionToEulerPlugin : public PluginPrivate {
public:
    void Load(int _argc, char **_argv) override {
        if (_argc != 5) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: " << _argv[0] << " <x> <y> <z> <w>" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        double x = std::stod(_argv[1]);
        double y = std::stod(_argv[2]);
        double z = std::stod(_argv[3]);
        double w = std::stod(_argv[4]);

        gz::math::Quaternion q(x, y, z, w);
        gz::math::Vector3 angles = q.Euler();
        
        // Print Euler angles
        std::cout << "Euler Angles (RPY): " << angles.X() << ", " << angles.Y() << ", " << angles.Z() << std::endl;
    }
};

GZ_REGISTER_SYSTEM_PLUGIN(QuaternionToEulerPlugin)

} // namespace gz
```

I am getting the following error:

```
/home/sdhar/workspace/src/gz-math/cmd/src/QuaternionToEulerPlugin.cpp:3:10: fatal error: gz/common/Plugin.hh: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <gz/common/Plugin.hh>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/quaternion_to_euler.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/quaternion_to_euler.dir/cmd/src/QuaternionToEulerPlugin.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1146: CMakeFiles/quaternion_to_euler.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

When I run `find` for the header, I do get results showing it inside ignition header directories.
How can I fix this? Is the definition of class correct in this code, and is there a better way to implement the desired tools?

Answer (score 0):

The include headers are specified (either implicitly or explicitly) via the CMake files of the project, so the only way to properly answer your question is that if you also provide the CMake files that you used to compile your project.

Beside that, if you want to write a command line tool, I guess you should write a file with `int main` function, not a class that derives from Plugin or similar interfaces.

Comment: I have currently reverted all the changes I had made previously and my cmake file is the one that came with the source install. I have linked it here: https://github.com/sdhar04/troubleshooting/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt
Could you tell me what all I should do to successfully add such a command line tool? I am planning to use the conversion equations already used inside other codes in the gz-math directory.

Comment: If you are modifying `gz-math`, it may be more useful if you share the branch of your fork of gz-math, as it is not useful to have just the CMakeLists.txt without the rest of the modifications.

Comment: I have left the CmakeLists.txt file as is and added the .cpp file in this branch: https://github.com/sdhar04/gz-math/tree/cmdline